# Parse out a datetime column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to parse out a datetime column into individual columns. For example I have a datetime field that looks like so:

```
Datetime
2017-05-15 00:00:00.000
2017-05-31 00:00:00.000
2017-01-21 00:00:00.000
2017-01-30 00:00:00.000
2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to break out the year, month, and day into separate columns (while preserving the original datetime column):

```
Year  Month  Day
2017  5      15
2017  5      31
2017  1      21
2017  1      30
2017  2      08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Datetime ,
    YEAR(Datetime) year, 
    MONTH(Datetime) month, 
    DAY(Datetime) day 
FROM 
    tablename;
```

Original column will be preserved along with 3 new columns. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select year(datefield), month(datefield), day(datefield) from your table
```

Try with this query, its self explanatory